# How do I use a node as the homepage?

Tags: 8

I feel like I'm misunderstanding something at a fundamental level when trying to author my drupal site. Two content types, both created by me, are available - `faq` and `page`. The `faq` type is a basic question + answer type, and will be pulled into an FAQ list block which I created. The `page` type is for a generic authored page, and has a `body` property of type `entity_reference_revision` which allows content to be authored using [Bootstrap Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_paragraphs).

Some sources online say that you just have to check the "Promote to front page" box to get a node to be the front page. Others say that you have to provide a URL path for the node. I've tried both, and neither causes the site's front page to display the authored page I've created.

Instead, on the front page, I see a list of the items that have been promoted to the front page.

How can I get my authored node to replace the content of front page, so that if I navigate to the root route (`/`), I see the authored page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the front page in Admin > Config > Site Information. “Promoted to frontoage” is not what you think it means in this context.

Comment: I thought "front page" in this context might refer to paging of a list of nodes. Is that more accurate?